# Setting Variables for each value from multiple values differentiated by commas in php

Tags: php

hello guys i am a problem i am trying to get my stuff to work but i am stuck 
problem is

i have a field which i fetch from my db using sql and echo it ,

```
$BaseID  = $row1['field_12'];
```

thing is sometimes few people have multiple ids so i am thinking of leting them use 2 ids which will be stored in db , and differentiated from each other via comma like : `12345,33213` 
id one = `12334`
and id two = `33213`

now doubt is i can fetch that values seperated by comma but how to set variable for them ? like

```
$Base1ID = "12345";
$Base2ID = "33213";
```

Comment: If there might be more than one you should rather normalize your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it are just 2 id's you can use explode + list so like

```
list($Base1ID, $Base2Id) = explode(",", $row1['field_12']);
```

Like that you assign the values in the array you would have gotten right away to the two variables you want.

If you would need to add more id's just add them to the list. like list($Base1ID, $Base2Id, $Base3Id).

If for one reason or the other the second is not filled $base2Id would be null as would expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHPs [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) function like below.

```
$BaseIds = explode(",", $row1['field_12']); //$row1['field_12'] = "123,456"
echo $BaseIds[0]; //123
echo $BaseIds[1]; //456
```